# Sequelize:: findAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

below are my js files. 
I've returned  an object from the model, and then trying to import it my controller js file. but it is throwing me the error that **admin_user.findAll is not a function.**

helloController.js

```
var DataTypes = require("sequelize/lib/data-types");
const dbconconfig = require("../dbseq.config.js").db;
var admin_users = require("../models/admin_users");
var admin_roles = require("../models/admin_roles");
const logger = require("tracer").colorConsole();
admin_roles = new sequelize(dbconconfig);
admin_users = new sequelize(dbconconfig);


async sendDB(req, res) {
    logger.info("db called");
    admin_users
      .findAll({
        include: [{ model: admin_roles }]
      })
      .then(admin_users => {
        const resObj = admin_users.map(admin_users => {
          return Object.assign(
            {}
```

Admin_user.js - which is returning admin_users of type (sequelize, DataTypes)

```
> admin_users.js



    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const admin_users = sequelize.define(
    "adminUsers",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(22),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: "id"
      },
      countryCode: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(10),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: "+91",
        field: "country_code"
      },
      mobileNo: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false,
        field: "mobile_no"
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "email"
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "first_name"
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "last_name"
      },
      lockVersion: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: "0",
        field: "lock_version"
      },
      blocked: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: "0",
        field: "blocked"
      },
      deleted: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: "0",
        field: "deleted"
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
        field: "created_at"
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
        field: "updated_at"
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: false,
        field: "password"
      },
      role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: true,
        field: "role"
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: "admin_users"
    }
  );

  adminUser.associate = models => {
    adminUser.belongsTo(models.adminRoles, {
      foreignKey: "id"
    });
  };
  return admin_users;
};
```

I am not able to figure out why it's not able to find the findAll function when 
 defined in sequelize.

i tried other methods to import the models, but nothing seems to be working.

please let me know if I should add more info/code for making this question comprehensible.

Comment: It should be db.admin_users .findAll({ include: [{ model: admin_roles }]  }).

Comment: Add db.admin_users.

Comment: hello Prabhjot, adding db gives me error- UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: db 
is not defined.  It's because i'm not using index.js  file. I'm importing the modules directly.

Answer (score 0):

there is issue associated with how the following lines work:

```
const dbconconfig = require("../dbseq.config.js").db;
var admin_users = require("../models/admin_users");
var admin_roles = require("../models/admin_roles");
admin_roles = new sequelize(dbconconfig);//You cannot have new sequelize
admin_users = new sequelize(dbconconfig);
```

Please refer the fllowing for your postgres setup:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli

The implementation is much cleaner this way and easy to maintain

Comment: once u install the cli globally and do sequelize init in the project root, the required files wil be created and new modals can be created using the cli commands